# Convert sql to linq query for authentication

Tags: sql, linq

Can someone convert this code into linq?

```
SELECT PWDCOMPARE('1', Password) FROM dbo.Users WHERE Username = 'Admin'
```

I would like to authenticate the user using linq statement.

The user password are generated using sql [`pwdencrypt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd822791.aspx) function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to wrap `PWDCOMPARE` in a UDF on your database and then to call that UDF via your `DataContext`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399416.aspx

So run this on your database:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_PWDCOMPARE (@pwd NVARCHAR(MAX),@pwdhash NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS BIT
BEGIN
  RETURN PWDCOMPARE(@pwd, @pwdhash)
END
```

Then add it to your `DataContext` in Visual Studio and call it like

```
var query =
  from user in db.Users
  where user.Username = "Admin"
  select db.fn_PWDCOMPARE("1", user.Password);
```